# HTML input field placeholder not displaying when binding input field to model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

I have an input field in which a user would type in a price. I want there to be a placeholder of `0.00`.

The placeholder only works if I remove model binding: `asp-for="Postage"`

Why is this happening? and how do I display the placeholder?

**HTML input field:**

```
@model Website.Models.Game

<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="Postage"></label>
   <div class="input-icon">
      <input type="number" class="form-control postageInput" placeholder="0.00" asp-for="Postage"/>
      <i>£</i>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The Model:**

```
public class Game {
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter postage amount or click on 'collection only'")]
  public decimal Postage {get; set;}

  [other properties here below...]
}
```

Comment: Try changing the type of `Postage` to `decimal?`. A `decimal` always has a value (0.0 by default), so it can never be "empty".

Comment: @JackA. decimal is not a valid type for the HTML input field. The type of the Postage property is already set to decimal in the model.

Comment: I'm referring to the model, not the HTML. Change it to a nullable decimal.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. That works, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder is shown when the value of the input is empty. Since a decimal always has a default value, it can't be empty. Changing the type of the `Postage` property on the model to a nullable decimal will fix this.

Try the code below to see the difference.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Postage"></label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="number" class="form-control postageInput" placeholder="0.00" asp-for="Postage" />
        <i>£</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="PostageNullable"></label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="number" class="form-control postageInput" placeholder="0.00" asp-for="PostageNullable" />
        <i>£</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public decimal Postage { get; set; }

public decimal? PostageNullable { get; set; }
```